# Error: Failed to fetch data server side on Next.js 13.4

Tags: next.js

So if I have a simple static page to be generated ideally at build time, so that is faster to load frontend, SEO is great, but to populate it I need data from an external API, like Strapi for instance, what's the best way to proceed with the new Next.js 13.4?

In Next.js 12 I'd create a `getStaticProps` and pass the data as props to my page.

But when it comes to Next.js 13.4, documentation says to do this: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#async-and-await-in-server-components

which looks exactly the same as my **page.js**:

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.MY_STRAPI_URL}/api/works`);

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {

  const works = await getData();
  
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-5">

      <div>
        {works && works?.data.map((item, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
              {item.attributes.Title}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

    </main>
  )
}
```

so why is this throwing

> error TypeError: fetch failed

the api `${process.env.MY_STRAPI_URL}/api/works` loads correctly when I try in the browser.

**EDIT**: a try catch error shows as:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:1337
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 1337
  }
}
```

it looks like Next.js is trying to use IPv6 ?

**SOLVED**: using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the MY_STRAPI_URL env.

Comment: maybe url is not correct. put the fetching logic inside `try/catch` and log the error

Comment: updated with the catch error

Answer (score 0):

Try double checking that the url is correct and adding the Authentication header.

Comment: tried both, no luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).